# Largest consecutive integer using basic operations and optimal digits?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, asymptotics, recreational-mathematics

If you are *first time reading this*, you may want to read the summary section last.

---

### **Solution summary and questions**

**Sequence values**

If the allowed operations are $(+,-,\times,\div)$ and parentheses $(\space)$, then the $f(n)$ is the number of consecutive integers we can make starting at $1$, given $n$ "digits" that each needs to be used exactly once. Equivalently, it is the largest integer we can make such that all smaller integers $\in\mathbb N$ can be made as well.

The $d$ is (optimal?) digit set used, where $d=\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}=(d_1,\dots,d_n)\in\mathbb N^n$.

So far I have the following data given $n=1,\dots,5$ digits to use (best so far):

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
n & 1&2&3&4&5&6\\
f(n)& 1 & 3 & 10 & 52 & 351 & ? \\
d & \{1\} & \{1, 2\} & \{1, 2, 4\} & \{2, 3, 4, 22\} & \{3, 6, 8, 12, 37\} & ? 
\end{array}

The $1,3,10$ are optimal. The $52$ entry is probably optimal, but I'm not sure if this can be proven.

The $f(5)\ge 351$ can be obtained using [$\{3, 6, 8, 12, 37\}$](https://pastebin.com/0AAVXCKc). I don't think it can be better.

Notice the weird similarity to the [$A052446$](https://oeis.org/search?q=1+3+10+52+351&sort=&language=&go=Search) sequence. Pure coincidence?

> **$Q_1$:** Is there any reason to suspect $f(4)=52,f(5)=351$ aren't the optimal solutions?

I haven't computed $f(n)$ for $n\ge6$ significatnly, I do not know how to do it efficiently.

There is a similar sequence such that [$A142153(n-1)$](https://oeis.org/A142153)$\approx f(n)$. The main difference being that linked sequence does not require all digits to be used when building a single number, giving it more freedom and expected larger terms than my sequence. The offset $(n-1)$ is due to it starting at $n=0$.

> **$Q_2$:** Can we find (compute) significant (lower bounds) $f_d(n)$ for $n\ge 6$?

I've found so far $f_d(6)\ge 2200$ using $d=\{2, 10, 13, 30, 49, 56\}$.

This was done with a simple `c++` search checking random digit sets: [*run it on repl.it*](https://repl.it/repls/GaseousImmenseDiskdrive).

I want to thank user [TheSimpliFire](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/471884/thesimplifire) for helping me run the code for $f(6)$. - The goal was to reach $f(6)\gt 3000$ if possible, but it looks hard unless the search can be optimized.

**Lower bound**

"Weak" lower exponential bound is known: $f(n)\gt 2^{n/3}$.

This is based on a related problem that allows only $1$'s and $(+,\times)$. - "Complexity of $n$".

This can be imporoved:

We can using $d=\{1,2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$, show that the following lower bounds hold:

- $f(n)\ge 2^n-1,n\ge 1$, which confirms optimal $f(1),f(2)=1,3$.
- $f(n)\ge 2^n+2,n\ge 3$, which confirms optimal $f(3)=10$.
- $f(n)\ge 2^n+10,n\ge 4$, which gives sub-optimal $f(4)\ge26$. Twice less than $f(4)=52$.

These bounds not hard to construct since this $d$ set has nice inductive properties.

But I haven't noticed a pattern that can be generalized to all $n$. It looks hard.

The best we can do with this set $d=\{d_i=2^{i-1},i=1,\dots,n\}$ of digits is:

$$f(n)\ge f_{d}(n)= 2^n-1+g(k)$$

where $g(k)=0,0,3,11,45,533\dots$ for $n\ge k$ where $k=1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$

> $Q_3:$ The $2^n$ grows slower than $g(k)$, for large $n$. Can we demystify $g(k)$ in terms of $n$?
>
> Equivalently, [What is the smallest number that can't be made using powers of two?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330306/318073)

Seems $f_d(n)=2^n+g(k)\ll f(n)$ for large $n$ for this $d=\{d_i=2^{i-1},i=1,\dots,n\}$.

Notice this $d$ is optimal for $n\le 3$. Can we find better digit sets for $n\ge 4$?

> $Q_4:$ What's a better set $d$ for which we can show higher lower bounds, in terms of on $n\ge 4$?

---

### Problem

> Up to how many consecutive integers $\in\mathbb N$, can be made using only the four basic
>   operations:
>
> - $+$ addition, $-$ subtraction, $\times$ multiplication, $\div$ division
>
> Given $n$ numbers ("digits") as building blocks, if parentheses are allowed?
>
> The goal is to build all integers from $1$ to $N$, while maximizing $N$, for given $n$ amount of digits.

We are given $d\in\mathbb N^n$ natural numbers ("digits") to work with.

We define $f_d(n)$ as maximal $N$ reachable using digits $d$, and $f(n)$ as maximal $f_d(n)$, given $n$.

### Example

Lets take $n=4,f_d(4)$ for example. We can try using $d=\{4,4,4,4\}$ four fours,

\begin{array}{}
1 &= (4 + 4 - 4) \div 4 \\
2 &= 4 - ((4 + 4) \div 4)  \\
3 &= (4 + 4 + 4) \div 4 \\
4 &= ((4 - 4) \times 4) + 4 \\
5 &= ((4\times4)+4)\div4 \\
6 &= ((4 + 4) \div 4) + 4 \\
7 &= 4 - (4\div4 - 4) \\
8 &= (4 + 4 + 4) - 4\\
9 &= (4\div4 + 4) + 4
\end{array}

And see that $f_{\{4,4,4,4\}}(4)=9$, because if you try hard enough, $10$ can't be made!

This means that $f(4)\ge f_d(4)= 9$ is at least nine.

We probably need a better set of digits $d$ to use, to make $10$ and beyond.

### **Definitions**

The digit set $d$ allows duplicate digits, and exactly $n$ digits (*elements*), and all digits (*elements*) must be used **exactly once**.

Given a fixed set of $n$ digits $d=\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$, we can construct consecutive integers from $1$ to $N\in\mathbb N$ using the basic operations and parentheses, but we can't construct $N+1$. Then we define the value $f_d(n)=N$.

Then we can define $f(n)=\max f_d(n)=N_{\text{max}}$, for $d\in\mathbb N^n$. That is, maximized $N$ obtained by using the optimal set of digits $d=\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$ for a given case of using $n$ digits.

> How to efficiently calculate, practically prove, $f(n)$ for given $n$?

The sets of digits are not ordered, so naturally:

WLOG we can assume $d_1\le d_2\le \dots \le d_n\implies d_n=\max\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$. Keep this in mind.

**Clarifications**

**All** integers $1,2,3,\dots,N$ must be **constructed**; Using **all** **digits** from digit set $d$ **exactly once.**

"Concatenation" is **not allowed**. That is, combining digits like $\{1,1\}$ to make $11$ is forbidden.

We are after optimal $d=\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$ that will allow us to construct the longest such sequence by applying the basic operations $+,-,\times,\div$ to the given digit set, when talking about maximal $N$.

### Solving small cases

**Cases $n=1,2$**

Trivially, $f(1)=1$ for $d=\{1\}$, since we can't apply binary operations to a single digit.

It can be easily seen that $f(2)=3$ is best, using optimal digits set $d=\{1,2\}$, here:

$$\begin{array}{}
1 &= 2 - 1 \\
2 &= 2 \times 1 \\
3 &= 2 + 1 \\
\end{array}$$

This is optimal: Since if we are given $d=\{d_1,d_2\}$, if not $d_2-d_1=1$ or not $d_1=d_2$, we can't make $1$, thus $f_d(2)=0$ in these $d$ cases. And we can't make $2$ unless they either add up to two, differ by two, or one is two times other. The only case that also extends to $3$, is the $d=\{1,2\}$ making this $f(2)=3$ proof easy.

**Case $n=3$**

It can be shown $f(3)=10$ if you observe enough cases. It can be seen that $f_d(3)= 3$ at best, if $d_3$ is too large. I have checked the rest (small enough) cases computationally.

The optimal set is $d=\{1,2,4\}$ and the solutions can be seen below:

$$\begin{array}{}
1 = 4 - (1 + 2) \\
2 = 4 - (1 \times 2) \\
3 = (1 - 2) + 4 \\
4 = (2 - 1) \times 4 \\
5 = 4 - (1 - 2) \\
6 = (1 \times 2) + 4 \\
7 = (1 + 2) + 4 \\
8 = (1 \times 2) \times 4 \\
9 = 1 + (2 \times 4) \\
10 = (1 + 4) \times 2 \\
\end{array}$$

**Case $n=4$**

The $f(4)=52$ is a conjectured solution, using $d=\{2,3,4,22\}$.

The previous records are $f_{\{1, 2, 5, 6\}}(4)=43, f_{\{1, 2, 5, 8\}}(4)=51$.

I have checked all $d_4\lt 64$, and tabulated maximal $N=y$ for subsets of digits such that $d_4=x$:

[image]

> Is it possible to prove $f(4)=52$?

**Update:** I extended the calculations to $d_4\le 100$ and the $52$ indeed seems to be optimal.

A similar problem to $f(4)$, but roots and exponentiation are allowed, was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323132/318073).

### Computing larger cases

**Cases $n\ge 5$**

> Is it possible to set up bounds or make progress in calculating these cases?
>
> If not, can we optimize the computation?

I'm running a brute force search.

For this result, all sets of digits with $d_5\le 15$ have been checked with record being $f_{\{2, 8, 9, 12, 13\}}=271$. But this is going on too slow in my python code to extend further. (Code based on [this four fours solver](https://gist.github.com/Radcliffe/fab1cefe6e2a3a23466539a7ecbc6edb).)

So I've decided to not brute force all sets, but try ones with $d_1,d_2=1,2$ or $d_1,d_2=2,3$ and $d_3\le d_4/2$, for $d_5\ge 20$. I've reached $d_5=45$ so far, with these restrictions on $d_1,d_2,d_3$.

This is where $f_{\{2, 3, 7, 8, 38\}}=324$ was found: [seen solutions](https://pastebin.com/hhwW7FKK).

**Update:** I've implemented the search in `c++` which is faster now.

I've checked all digits up to $d_5 \le 35$ so far, where the best was $f(5)=333$.

I've also checked a restricted search where $d_5\le 120$ but $d_4\le 12$ so far, which is where the newest $f(5)=351$ was found. I've also checked a restricted search where $d_5\le 60$ but $d_4\le 24$ so far,  with no better results.

### Growth of $f(n)$?

> Can we analyse and give bounds on growth of $f(n)$?

The best I have so far is: using $d_i=2^{i-1}$ to show $f(n)\gt 2^n,n\gt 2$.

Here is "weak" linear bound (explicit construction) example to get inspired:

**Weak linear lower bound (explicitly constructive)**

For $d$, we pick $\{1,\dots,1\}$ all $1$'s. We can then make $1,\dots,2n-4$ easily:

$$\begin{array}{}
1 &= (1+1)-(1\times1\times\dots\times 1) &= 2 - 1\\
2 &= (1+1)\times(1\times1\times\dots\times 1) &= 2 \times 1\\
3 &= (1+1)+(1\times1\times\dots\times 1) &= 2 + 1\\
4 &= (1+1)+1+(1\times1\times\dots\times 1) &= 2 + 1 + 1\\
\dots & & \\
n &= (1+1)+(1+1+1+\dots+ 1) &= 2 + (n-2) \\
n &= (1+1)\times(1+1)+(1+1+\dots+ 1) &= 2\cdot2 + (n-4) \\
n+1 &= (1+1)\times(1+1+1)+(1+\dots+ 1) &= 2\cdot3 + (n-5) \\
n+2 &= (1+1)\times(1+1+1+1)+(1+\dots+ 1) &= 2\cdot4 + (n-6) \\
\dots & & \\
2n-4 &= (1+1)\times(1+1+1+\dots+ 1) &= 2(n-2) + (n-n)
\end{array}$$

We have now shown $f(n)\ge 2n-4$ with this trivial digit set.

Note that this works if we replace $(1+1)$ with $(d_n\div d_{n-1})$ if $d_{n-1}=d_n/2$, so we also have an infinite family of digit sets that can achieve at least $2n-4$, since $d_n\in\mathbb N$ can be any digit.

Perhaps instead of $(1+1)$, we can use this and pick $d_n/2=2n-3$ to continue the construction? Note that we could also replace other $1$'s with similar substitutions and keep the initial construction still valid.

> Can we do better with this idea, and show it is better than exponential bound given below?
>
> This idea was discussed by user @Countingstuff in the comments (second-by-date comment).

**Exponential lower bound (based on a related problem)**

The bound is "weak" due to ignoring $(-,\div)$ operations, and due to using only $1$'s as digits.

Lets restrict the problem to only $(+,\times)$ operations, and define this restricted $\overline{f}(n)$. We have:

$$
f(n)\ge \overline{f}(n)
$$

By definition. For $\overline{f_d}$, optimal $d$ consists of pure $1$'s, since otherwise, $N=1$ can't be made.

Now this becomes related to the "*Complexity of natural number $n$*" problem. That is, [$a(N)$ - minimal number of $1$'s for expressing $N$ using $1$'s and $+,\times$](https://oeis.org/A005245). Now, this has known bounds:

> $3\log_2N \ge a(N) \ge 3\log_3N$,$\space$ [R. K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Sect. F26.].
>
> The upper bound is obtained by expanding $N$ in binary with Horner's algorithm. Improving the upper bound is still an open problem.

We will use the upper bound for $a(N)$ to get the "weak" lower bound for $f(n)$.

If $N_0$ some number, notice that $a(N_0)$ defines the price of building $N_0$, in terms of the amount of digits. And since the price $a(N)$ is bounded above by a monotone increasing function, if we can build $N_0$ with at least the bound given amount of digits, we can also build numbers $1,\dots, N_0$ with that many or less digits, thus $N\ge N_0$.

Also, an important fact is that if we can build $N_0$ with $n$ digits, we can build it with $\ge n$ digits as well. This is due to optimal $d$ being a set of $1$'s for restricted $\overline{f_d}$, so we can multiply two digits $1$'s to reduce the case of digits, down to $n$, for every case $\gt n$.

So, by the definition of $a(N)$ and $\overline{f}(n)$ we have:

$$\begin{array}{}
k(N)\ge a(N_0) \implies \overline{f}(k(N_0))\ge N_0 \\
\end{array}$$

So we can use the result on bounds of $a(N)$ to establish:

$$
3\log_2N_0 \ge a(N_0) \implies \overline{f}(3\log_2 N_0)\ge N_0 \implies \overline{f}(n)\ge 2^{n/3}
$$

By substitution $n=3\log_2 N_0\implies N_0=2^{n/3}$. We have obtained:

An exponential lower bound for the original problem, $f(n)\ge 2^{n/3}$ follows from $f(n)\ge\overline{f}(n)$.

But note that $f(n)\gt 2^{n/3}$ it actually certainly strict. For example, last two digits can be $d_0,d_0$ where $d_0=\frac12 2^{(n-1)/3}$. The $(d_0/d_0)=1$ leaves us with $n-1$ case of $1$'s, so we can reach $2^{(n-1)/3}$ at least. Now use $(d_0+d_0)=2^{(n-1)/3}$. Now we are left with $n-2$ case of $1$'s free to use again. Which means we can reach at least $2^{(n-1)/3}+2^{(n-2)/3}\gt 2^{n/3},n\gt 3$.

I believe $f(n)\gg \overline{f}(x)\ge 2^{n/3}$ is actually much greater than this "weak" bound.

**Questions regarding bounds**

> Can we improve this by getting a "non-weak", and better bound? - Perhaps use the fact that $(-,\div)$ allows extending the explicit weak linear construction I mentioned earlier?
>
> Can we obtain non-trivial upper bounds?

A trivial upper bound can be the upper bound on number of (not necessarily consecutive) distinct positive integers that can be built with the given operations and $n$ digits.

I'm not sure how I would establish a non-trivial upper bound. - Bound that uses the fact that integers are consecutive. Idea is to find upper bound on the "hole" that breaks the consecutive sequence?

**Update on lower bound**

The $f(n)\gt 2^n,n\gt 2$ was included in the summary section at the beginning, more details are there.

---

Partial answers answering any point of this question are appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why $\{1,3\}$ isn't a better two-digit set.

Comment: I only have an observation for your last question. Suppose f(n) = N, so f(n) >= N -1 and either N or N - 1 even. But now take D = {d_1, ..., d_n} a witness to f(n). Now consider D = {d_1, ..., d_n, N, N / 2, N /2}, (or (N - 1) / 2 if N - 1 even). Well with D we can make 1 to N in the way from before + (N - N / 2 - N / 2), and can also make N + 1 to N via the same from before + (N + N / 2 - N / 2). Meaning d_(n + 3) >= 2(d_(n) - 1) implying some exponentional bound.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Forgive me for not clarifying that properly. - Just to clarify fully: $\{1,3\}$ has maximal $N=0$ since it can't build $1$. When finding $f(n)=N$ where $N$ is maximal, we need to be able to build **all consecutive** numbers from $1$ to $N$. We can't have any holes in the sequence. We also **must** use all digits in the set; *Like puzzle pieces from a puzzle box.* I hope everything else is clear enough.

Comment: Is non-exact division allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Integer division is not allowed. The $\div$ is an exact fraction. Neither is rounding, floor, ceiling, or other functions that are not the classic four basic operations $(+,-,\times,\div)$.

Comment: Sorry about the typos in my previous comment. It's worth noting that in fact, by doing $+ (N + N/2 + N/2)$ I can get from $2N+1$ to $3N$. Which implies a bound of $3^{n/3}$. In fact we can do better than this, consider $\{N, 2, N/2, N/2\}$. Now $0 = (N/(N/2) - 2)(N/2)$, $N = N + 2(N/2 - N/2)$, $2N= 2N + (N/2 -N/2)$, $3N=2N + N/2 + N/2$, $4N = 2(N + N/2 + N/2)$ Which implies a bound like $5^{n/4}$, this has the nice property that we have at least started to use * and /.

Comment: @Countingstuff I'll have to take a closer look into extending the construction - starting from a fixed explicit $d$ of size $n$ and reaching some $a^{n/b}$? - If you think you can clearly formulate a construction and show a good bound, feel free to formulate that as a partial answer. Also note that more generally given $d=\{d_1,d_1/b_1,d_2,d_2/b_2,d_3,d_3/b_3,\dots,d_m,d_m/b_m\}$ is equivalent to $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m\}$ by division of $(d_k/(d_k/b_k))$. Instead of pairs, we can maybe form different $l$-sized tuples and try give constructions $a^m$ to $a^{m-1}$,... $a^0$ and work backwards.