# Smallest number not expressible using first $n$ powers of $2$ (exactly once each), with $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, and parentheses?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

**Motivation**

Solution to this problem is a lower bound for a more [general problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325820/318073).

**Problem**

> Given first $n$ powers of two: $1,2,4,8,16,\dots,2^{n-1}$ that all need to be used exactly once per number expressed, what is the smallest positive integer $f(n)$ that can't be made, if we can use the four basic arithmetic operations $(+,-,\times,\div)$, and parentheses?

The $f(1)=2$ is trivial, as well as $f(2)=4$, for example given $\{1,2\}$:

$$\begin{array}{}
1 &= 2-1 \\
2 &= 2\times 1 \\
3 &= 2+1
\end{array}$$

But we can't make four which is trivial to conclude, so $f(2)=4$.

**Progress**

It is clearly true $f(n+1)\ge f(n)$ since we can reduce the $n+1$ case to $n$ case by subtracting last two powers. This means that we can rebuild all the numbers from previous case at least. Even more so, we can inductively show that:

- $f(n)\ge2^n$, for all $n\ge1$ by constructing first $2^n-1$ numbers.

But I'm not sure how to extend the construction for more numbers to reach the full $f(n)$.

The solutions so far, along with pattern for $f(n)$:

$$\begin{array}{}
n & f(n) & f(n+1)\ge f(n)\ge 2^n \\
1 & 2 & 2^1 \\
2 & 4 & 2^2 + 0 \\
3 & 11 & 2^3 + 0 + 3 \\
4 & 27 & 2^4 + 0 + 3 + 8\\
5 & 77 & 2^5 + 0 + 3 + 8 + 34\\
6 & 597 & 2^6 + 0 + 3 + 8 + 34 + 488\\
7 & 2473 & 2^7 + 0 + 3 + 8 + 34 + 488 + 1812\\
8 & 9643 & 2^8 + 0 + 3 + 8 + 34 + 488 + 1812 + 7042 \\
9 & ? & 2^9 + 0 + 3 + 8 + 34 + 488 + 1812 + 7042 + ??
\end{array}$$

Here is the brute force output for [$n=4,5,6$](https://pastebin.com/AxUKmnGm).

Relevant: [$A071314$](https://oeis.org/A071314) - Note that there we are allowed to not use all powers per expression, unlike here. Also note that there for some reason $a(6)=595$, meaning they don't allow to build $595$ (see end of this post how we can actually make it). I think there "intermediate fractions" are not allowed, or the sequence terms are incorrect.

Since $f(n+1)\ge f(n)$, notice $f(n+1)=f(n)+g(n)$, $g(n)=0,3,8,34,488,1812,7042,\dots$

> Is it possible to find $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ for all $n$?
>
> Can we find $g(n)$ or compute it efficiently?

Are there similar problems with results that can provide insight into this problem?

---

**To clarify the base construction**

We can prove first $2^n-1$ numbers can always be constructed inductively. Assume this is true:

- The $2^n-1$ is simply the sum of the powers. The last step is obtainable.
- The $2^{n-1}$ is the last term, and previous case $(n-1)$ can by assumption build all numbers from $1$ to $2^{n-1}-1$. Summing these terms gives us all numbers from $2^{n-1}$ to $2^n-1$. Repeat this for $(n-2)$ and so on until you reach the base case $1$.
- From $n,\dots,1$ we reached the base case $\{1\}$ which trivially builds $1$. We can build all numbers from $1$ to $2^n-1$ which was shown inductively.

This means $f(n)\ge 2^n$ for $n\ge 1$. Notice we haven't used division yet.

**Extending the construction**

*We ca now try to extend the construction:* Let $d=2^{n-1}$ largest power.

For $n\ge3$, we can show we can obtain the $3$ extra terms:

- $d\cdot 2 \cdot 1,\space  d\cdot 2 + 1,\space  (d + 1)\cdot 2$
- So we have: $f(n)\ge 2^n+3,n\ge 3$, and for this case $f(3)=11$.

For $n\ge4$, we can show we can obtain the $8$ extra terms:

- $d\cdot 2 +  (4-1),\space d\cdot 2 +  (4\cdot1),\space  d\cdot 2 +  (4+1),\space   (d +1)\cdot 2 +  4$,
- $\space  (d +4)\cdot 2 -1,\space  (d +4)\cdot 2 \cdot1,\space  (d +4)\cdot 2 +1,\space  (d +4+1)\cdot 2$,
- So we have: $f(n)\ge 2^n+11,n\ge 4$, and for this case $f(4)=27$.

And so on, for $f(5),f(6),\dots$ we can construct $34,488,\dots$ extra terms. But I do not see a pattern for generally extending $n$ to $n+1$.

**Use of division $(\div)$**

Also note that these first five values of $f(n)$ can be obtained without the use of division. And the $f(6)$ would be $595$ if division is not allowed, but with division allowed it is $597$, so after $n\ge 6$, the division is significant.

That is, $595$ has only one representation possible (ignoring permutations of it):

$$
595 = (1 + 16 + 4/8 )\times(2 + 32) 
$$

Numbers usually tend to have multiple representations.

This is also the one of the only numbers, that require "intermediate fractions", like $4/8$, to be made. The only other such number so far, is $2471$. All but these two numbers can be made without "intermediate fractions", up to and including all $n\le 8$ cases.

Comment: For $n>2$ $f(n)>2^n.$ Because $2^n = \left(2^1\right)\cdot \left(2^{n-1}\right).$

Comment: I'm not using exponentiation, I am using the product of two of the terms, $2^1=2$ and $2^{n-1}.$ For example, when $n=3,$ $8=2\cdot 4.$

Comment: "Notice we haven't used multiplication or division yet" -- but we *do* need multiplication already to arrive at $f(2)\ge 4$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I meant "division", thanks for pointing this out. Multiplication is used only to "glue" the inductive steps for numbers $\lt 2^n$, and only non-trivially significant for constructing larger numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense

Comment: All in all the induction step for $f(n)\ge 2^n$ should rather run like this: Assume $f(n-1)\ge 2^{n-1}$. Then to represent $k$ with $1,2,4,\ldots, 2^{n-1}$, we can a) substitute $2^{n-2}$ with $(2^{n-1}-2^{n-2})$ in an $(n-1)$ representation of $k$ if $1\le k\le 2^{n-1}-1$; b) use $2^{n-1}+$ an $(n-1)$ representation of $k-2^{n-1}$ if $2^{n-1}+1\le k\le 2^n-1$; or c) use $2^{n-1}\times $ an $(n-1)$ representation of $1$ if $k=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I agree that's the better way to write it. My *induction* lacks those precise details.

Comment: @Blue $f(n+1)\ge f(n)$ since you can subtract last two terms to reduce the case from $n+1$ to $n$ always. In this case, you can repeat this until we have case $n=1$, this makes $1$ always possible. For example if we have $1,2,4,8$ we can get $\{1,2,(8-4)\}\equiv\{1,2,4\}\equiv\{1,(4-2)\}\equiv\{1,2\}\equiv\{2-1\}\equiv\{1\}$.

Comment: @Vepir: Ah, yes. I *did* miss something. :)